# Ajax javascript n jquery src reference issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to Jquery and AJAX.  I am trying to upload the file using AJAX call. When I set the script reference as from website, its working fine, but when I download it and set reference as local folder, its  not working. What is wrong with my code?

When I use :

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

its working fine,

but when I use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/Upload/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">
```

its not working......

Comment: Are you sure that folder is accessible to the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `jquery.form.js` library in your website folder under `js` folder, and

*Change*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">
```

*To*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

This version points to a file on that web site:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

This version points to a file on your LOCAL server (machine) via port 8080 (usually NOT a great idea)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/Upload/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

This verison points to a `js` folder relative to the page it is linked on

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">
```

In order to use a file locally (like the last two), you  will need to **download that file, and save it to your web server (or local server) in a folder**.  In the second example, this would mean saving it to the `Upload\js` folder at the root of your local servers site (that machine).

In the third example, you would need to find the page it is linked in, create (if not present) a `js` folder under that folder and save the js file at that location.

Note that it is always a good idea to use the original name form or something similar rather than jQuery.js - as that is often confused with the jQuery library itself.

An examples might be save it as:

- jquery.form.js
- malsup.jquery.form.js
- malsup.version1.jquery.form.js

or some such named instance.

NOTE One way of making this as generic as might be would be to use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Upload/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

This points to a folder called Upload with a sub folder js (Upload\js)which is based at the root of your web site.  For instance if your site is based at your windows e: drive in a wwwroot folder it might be:

```
E:\wwwroot\Upload\js\malsup.jquery.form.js
```